# What is the version of the scanned OS?

Tags: windows, nmap, metasploit

I've scanned a target with metasploit `scanner/smb/smb_version` and `nmap -O`.

- **smb_version**: Windows 2016 Standard (build:14393)
- **Nmap**: Windows Server 2008 R2 - 2012; CPE: cpe:/o:microsoft:windows

What is the OS of my target? I don't understand the difference.

Comment: Are you aware of how an smb scan works and how `nmap -O` works to detect the OS?

Comment: Actually no, thank you for your anwser. I will deeply research about your point.

Comment: As mentioned by Schroeder, check out the manuals for any tools you use to get a better idea of how the tool works. `man nmap` will give you a detailed manual for nmap, whereas `nmap --help` will only give you a summarised version which can lack a lot of valuable detail. To get more familiar with the SMB protocol, check out the official Microsoft documentation: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/file-server/file-server-smb-overview Official documentation is always the first place to start understanding a tool or service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always, always, always read the manual of the tools you use. They will educate you on how they work and give you an idea about their weaknesses.

[`smb_version`](https://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/scanner-smb-auxiliary-modules/):

> The smb_version scanner connects to each workstation ... and
> determines the version of the SMB service that is running.

[`nmap -O`](https://nmap.org/book/man-os-detection.html):

> ... remote OS detection using TCP/IP stack fingerprinting ...

> Nmap compares the results to its nmap-os-db database of more than 2,600 known OS fingerprints and prints out the OS details if there is a match.

So, as you can see, the `smb_version` scan connects to the Windows SMB service and asks it what version it is. `nmap` analyses the TCP/IP traffic and makes a guess.

Never, ever, use a tool blindly and take the answers at face value.

Comment: So, as I understand verison of SMB service and SMB protokol are different. Am I correct?
- SMB protocol versions: SMBv1, SMBv2, SMBv3 
- SMB service versions: Windows Standart 2016 etc.